# How do i find Percentage in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql

I have a table below..

```
Region   Product
East     Orange
West     Apple
North    Apple
West     Orange
South    Banana
West     Banana
```

How do i find out the percentage of Apple and orange for respective region to the total number of records in column?

Comment: You can use stored procedure to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking for the percentage of each combination of region/product vs. the whole table.

```
SELECT region, product, COUNT(*)*100.0/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable) AS percentage
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE product in ('Apple','Orange')
    GROUP BY region, product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  region,
  sum(case when product in ('orange', 'apple') then 1 else 0 end) / (count(region) * 1.0) as percentage
from 
  [insert_table_name]
group by
  region
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
    SELECT Region, Apples_and_Oranges/Total_Products AS Percent_Apples_and_Oranges
      FROM (

    SELECT Region, SUM(CASE WHEN Product = 'Apple' OR Product = 'Orange' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Apples_and_Oranges, 
COUNT(*) AS Total_Products
    FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY Region
    ) AS A
```